# Why do I see answered questions in the Unanswered questions list?

Tags: discussion

If I go to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/unanswered, I see a lot of questions answered. Maybe it's caching of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question with no **upvoted** answers is considered to be unanswered.

There is explanatory text in the right column (as there is for all the tabs).

[image: unanswered tab screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but if you see closely, Unanswered Questions have 4 sub-tabs which are :

- mytags
- newest
- votes
- no answers

So now click on **Unanswered Questions** & than click on **no answers** sub tab, now you won't see any answered questions.

Comment: Ah. Thx for your answer. The point I was trying to make is this. From a UI point of view, and I am a user at this point, a "no answers" tab should be superfluous since I am already in the Unanswered tab. So my suggestion would be to remove the tab "no answers" and show only unanswered questions. (looks like an example of Steve Krug's "Don't make me think" :) )

Comment: you are welcome, but yea those tabs are useful sometimes, say you want to go through questions specifically the one's your tags belongs too, or sort by vote, so its pretty much fine :)